# RCTAppdelegate.h is not found in Mac M2

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-firebase

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"



#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
  self.moduleName = @"abcApp";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

/// This method controls whether the `concurrentRoot`feature of React18 is turned on or off.
///
/// @see: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html
/// @note: This requires to be rendering on Fabric (i.e. on the New Architecture).
/// @return: `true` if the `concurrentRoot` feature is enabled. Otherwise, it returns `false`.
- (BOOL)concurrentRootEnabled
{
  return true;
}

@end
```

I install react-native-firebase@17.4.2 setup in react-native@0.71.6.After following all the steps from the doucments. I am unable to build the app is ios. Giving me this error
RCTAppdelegate.h file is not found.

Comment: Can you update with your podfile please? That could be related